# Bypass a program that runs before desktop?

Tags: windows, ssd, migration, autorun, paragon

What I mean by that is programs that say "a restart is required to do blah" and then run in a low-level mode before the operating system is loaded the next time you boot. Examples of this are Spybot S&D, Norton Ghost, memtest etc. I'm wondering if there's a way to bypass the automatic boot, because the particular software that I'm using (paragon migrate to SSD) is running continuously each time I reboot, and each time it recopies my entire disk to my SSD so its getting kind of annoying. Plus if I unplug the hard drive after its done copying and boot from the SSD, the clever geniuses at Paragon have made it so the cloned image will still boot into paragon from the SSD, which then proceeds to *erase itself*. Help?

Answer (score 1):

(This is assuming you're using Windows.) If it's a service, it can be disabled in Computer Management (Start>right-click on (My) Computer, hit Manage). Go to "Services", right-click on the service, hit Properties, and change it from "Automatic" to "Manual" or "Disabled".
If it doesn't run as a service, `autoruns` from live.sysinternals.com should do the trick—it allows you to disable any startup program. Make sure you Run as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't want to download autoruns from sysinternals. You can simply use the builtin System Configuration Utility. Just go to

```
Start
Run 
type in "msconfig"
press enter
click on startup tab
uncheck the process  you don't want to start automatically.
OK
```

Answer (score 0):

If the application in question is really running during system startup, then it is probably a [native application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897447).  Look at the registry value

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute
```

and remove the unwanted application from the list.  Make sure you don't remove autocheck, this is part of Windows.