# tool that used to disable services from starting up automatically on Microsoft Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

i have got a question on What is the tool used to disable services from starting up automatically on Microsoft Windows 2008 R2?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/390482/bypass-a-program-that-runs-before-desktop/390499?s=5|1.5348#390499 assuming it is like most of the other windows , these answers would be the thing.  If you were referring to remote methods , then (as always) you need to be very clear and explicit about everything you are trying to do, and even all the reasons you wish to do so, and what exactally you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Control panel | services will display a list of all services and each service can be set to automatic, manual or disable at startup.